# Wordpress MySQL Search and replace with wildcard?

Tags: posts, mysql, sql, post-content

I'm trying to search and replace for a link with wildcard in phpMyadmin.

If I simulate this query

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="/spammy-url">.</a>','.');
```

It finds the exact match and will replace them successfully.

However due to the amount of links with different URL's i'd like to wildcard the query, If I navigate to the wp_posts table and do a search and replace, it displays all the correct entries that need to be replaced, however the column showing the "replaced" string doesnt change.

I thought doing the following would do it :

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="%">.</a>','.');
```

But it's not returning any results.   Do wildcards not work with search and replace in this way ?

If someone could explain where I am going wrong that would be great.

## UPDATE

I have just tried to run the query via SSH and this is the notice I get :

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 3196  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

So it found the rows required to change,  but didnt change them.  I think its something to do with the wildcard ( obviously ) but everything im trying comes up with the same result.

Comment: No as they don't do wildcard search and replace, hence having to revert to Mysql

Comment: MySQL does not support the syntax you're attempting. If you want to do this type of replace you'll need to use a regular expression with [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace). Note that this only works in MySQL 8+, which is quite new. Any further questions on pure MySQL should be asked at stackoverflow.com. They're off-topic here.

Comment: Ah that makes sense,  I use MariaDB 10+ which I believe also supports it : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/ 

Just to figure out what the ragex would be now :S  Any help appreciated .

Comment: You're more likely to get help for generic SQL questions on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks , Yes I think im on the right track now.  Found a few related questions regarding REGXP REPLACE,  just needed to be pointed in the right direction :)  Thanks Jacob